# Помогите исправить программу для  произвольного количества.

Tags: jquery

Уважаемые профессионалы своего дела. Я сам недавно как начал изучать jQuery, у меня возникла такая проблема. Вот скачал готовую галерею, на обороте 5 блоков (всего 14), справа и слева кнопки для смены блоков. Всего находится 14 блоков (товар). Я добавил снизу, отдельно 4 блока (Категория)

> {Блок_1 Блок_2 Блок_3 Блок_4}

Первые 5 товаров относится к 1й категории (`Блок_1`), следующие 4 товара 2й категории (`Блок_2`), следующие 3 товара к 3й категории (`Блок_3`). Следующие 2 товара к 4й категории (`Блок_4`). Блоки просто подсвечиваются. Вот мой HTML-код:

```
<ul>
        <li><div class="news-text"><p>!1!Text</p></div></li>       
        <li><div class="news-text"><p>!2!Text</p></div></li>
        <li><div class="news-text"><p>!3!Text</p></div></li>
        <li><div class="news-text"><p>!4!Text</p></div></li>
        <li><div class="news-text"><p>!5!Text</p></div></li>
        <li><div class="news-text"><p>!6!Text</p></div></li>
        <li><div class="news-text"><p>!7!Text</p></div></li>
        <li><div class="news-text"><p>!8!Text</p></div></li>
        <li><div class="news-text"><p>!9!Text</p></div></li>
        <li><div class="news-text"><p>!10!Text</p></div></li>
        <li><div class="news-text"><p>!11!Text</p></div></li>
        <li><div class="news-text"><p>!12!Text</p></div></li>
        <li><div class="news-text"><p>!13!Text</p></div></li>
        <li><div class="news-text"><p>!14!Text</p></div></li>
   </ul>
</div>
<div class="buttom_block">
     <ul>
        <li class="item1"> 1_блок  </li>
        <li class="item2"> 2_блок  </li>
        <li class="item3"> 3_блок  </li>
        <li class="item4"> 4_блок  </li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

JS файл. То, что я добавил:

```
var index = 1;
function next_button(index,current){
        if (index <= 4) $('.item1').addClass("class");
        if (index == 5) {
          $('.item1').removeClass("class");
          $('.item2').addClass("class");
        }
        if (index == 9) {
          $('.item2').removeClass("class");
          $('.item3').addClass("class");
        }
        if (index == 12) {
          $('.item3').removeClass("class");
          $('.item4').addClass("class");
        }
        if (index == 14) {
                 $('.item4').removeClass("class");
                 $('.item1').addClass("class");
        }
}               
function prev_button(index){
      if (index >= 13 && index <= 14) 
           $('.item4').addClass("class");
      if (index >= 10 && index <= 12){
           $('.item4').removeClass("class");
          $('.item3').addClass("class");
           }
      if (index >= 6 && index <= 9){
           $('.item3').removeClass("class");
          $('.item2').addClass("class");
           }
      if (index >= 1 && index <= 5){
           $('.item2').removeClass("class");
          $('.item1').addClass("class");
           }
      if (index==14)  $('.item1').removeClass("class");
}
```

Это я добавил в сами кнопки. Для `Next`:

```
next_button(index,current);
index++;
if (index>14) index= index-14;
```

Для `Prev`:

```
index--;
if (index==0) index = index+14;
prev_button(index);
```

Как сделать, чтобы была возможность добавить произвольное количество товаров (к примеру, если добавить к 1му блоку еще несколько товаров)? Т.е чтобы можно было в HTML файле указать какой товар относится к какому блоку. Я надеюсь кто-нибудь откликнется на мою проблему. Весьма буду благодарен за любую полезную информацию.
Спасибо заранее!

Comment: Можно хранить количество элементов на каждой странице массивом, и данные для if-ов брать из него.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сделать, например, так:
При создании div укажите ему атрибут id и пусть, например, если товар относится к первой группе, id начинается с символа **a**, если товар со второй группы - id начинается с символа **b** и т.д. Код будет примерно таким:

```
<ul>
//товары первой группы
        <li><div class="news-text" id=a1><p>!1!Text</p></div></li>       
        <li><div class="news-text" id=a2><p>!2!Text</p></div></li>
        <li><div class="news-text" id=a3><p>!3!Text</p></div></li>
        <li><div class="news-text" id=a4><p>!4!Text</p></div></li>
//товары второй группы
        <li><div class="news-text" id=b1><p>!5!Text</p></div></li>
        <li><div class="news-text" id=b2><p>!6!Text</p></div></li>
        <li><div class="news-text" id=b3><p>!7!Text</p></div></li>

   </ul>
```

Тогда вместо проверок какой index имеет заданный элемент Вам нужно будет проверять какое имя имеет этот элемент, и, если это имя начинается с буквы **а**, то Вы точно сможете утверждать, что товар относиться к первой группе. Аналогично, если имя элемента начинается с буквы **b**, то Вы точно знаете, что товар относится ко второй группе и т.д.

В итоге, если у Вас всего 4 группы товаров, то у Вас будет только 4 условия **if**

Можно и другим способом решить эту проблему. У Вас все элементы имеют один и тот же класс, а что, если создать 4 класса - для каждой группы свой. Тогда нужно проверять не индексы, а имеет ли заданный элемент определенный класс.

Comment: function next_button(index,kol){
    $("#buttom_block ul").children().css('background','#666'); 
    $('#'+$('li').eq(index-1).attr('class')).css('background','#3f4078');
 if (index == kol+1) {
        $('#'+$("#buttom_block ul li:last").attr('id')).css('background','#666');
             $('#1').css('background','#3F4078');
  }
}

Comment: function prev_button(index,kol){
    $("#buttom_block ul").children().css('background','#666');
    $('#'+$('li').eq(index-1).attr('class')).css('background','#3f4078');  
 if (index == kol) {
        $('#1').css('background','#666666');
              $('#'+$("#buttom_block ul li:last").attr('id')).css('background','#3f4078');
  }
}

Comment: это в само событие<br>
next_button(index+1,kol);<br>
 index++;<br>
 if (index>=kol) index= index-kol;<br>
<br>
index--;<br>
if (index==0) index = index+kol;<br>
prev_button(index,kol);